# How to use bower components on Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, bower

I'm new with Laravel 5 and I'm creating a new project, I've installed some dependencies using bower.

Right now I've added angular using:

```
bower install angular
```

And it created a folder named "bower_components" and inside a folder with all angularjs files.

My question is what is the right way to add angularjs to my public folder so I can use it on my project?

Comment: Place the `bower_components` directory in your public folder. See https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md#directory

Comment: You should consider using NPM instead of Bower.